# WP8 Custom Contact Store

Tags: windows-phone-8

I tried to create custom contact store at WP8. My code (from msdn):

```
     async public void AddContact(string remoteId, string givenName, string familyName, string email, string codeName)
    {
        ContactStore store = await ContactStore.CreateOrOpenAsync();
    }

    private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AddContact("0", "Sample", "Sample", "sample@tut.by", "32");

    }
```

When I click on button it occurs  System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access is denied. .

I don't understand, what happens?

Comment: The exception is triggered on which line? Also, could you provide the details of the exception? (message, inner exception if any, callstack, ...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try add **ID_CAP_CONTACTS** capability into WMAppManifest.xml file in your project.

UnauthorizedAccessException is a common exception type which is thrown when a certain capability is missing from manifest. We can only wonder why MS guys forgot to add such an important tip into MSDN docs.